# Xcode build on different machines from same commit works different

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit, xcode4.3

I build project from head commit in my repository on my iMac. and

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

returned correct `SKProduct` objects in `response.products`.

But when i build the same project from the same commit on my Macbook Air this method returns all my in-app id's in `response.invalidProductIdentifiers`.

How could I fix this weird behavior?

p.s. I removed all folders from projname.xcodeproj folder except project.xcodeproj file on both machines, but result still the same.

UPD. as i understand build from Macbook Air installed not to the development sandbox. investigating..

Comment: Is the same version of Xcode installed on both machines with the same SDKs etc?

Comment: yes. all the same. latest xcode 4.3.1 with iOS 5.1 SDK

Comment: And even same provisioning profile and the same developer certificates on both machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happend because each XCode installs application in separate sandbox. When app was installed by one XCode, and after that installed by second XCode (without deleting previous one) - application appears in broken sandbox and StoreKit works strange.

I hope this answer helps someone.